# Find duplicate rows in PostgreSQL with additional criteria

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `entries` that has the following columns: `case_id`, `number` and `filed_on`.

If I were only looking for duplicates where the `case_id` and `number` were the same, I would use the following query:

```
SELECT case_id, number, count(*) FROM entries GROUP BY case_id, number HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

But I would like to filter by an additional criterion, namely, that at least 1 of the duplicate rows has a filed_on that is `null`.

I thought the following query would work, but I think it gives me duplicate rows where ALL the duplicates have `filed_on` set to `null`, instead of duplicate rows where 1 or more of the rows have `filed_on` of `null`:

```
SELECT case_id, number, count(*) FROM entries WHERE filed_on IS NULL GROUP BY case_id, number HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Any ideas for how I can modify this query to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a condition which is checked after grouping, not before, i.e. `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. Note that the condition should either be one of grouping fields or aggregate (just like in `SELECT`). You should be able to count number of rows which satisfies the condition like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288725/767632):

```
SELECT case_id, number, count(*)
FROM entries
GROUP BY case_id, number
HAVING (count(*) > 1) AND (count(CASE WHEN filed_on IS NULL THEN 1 END) >= 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d877/5)