# Count(case when) redshift sql - receiving groupby error

Tags: case, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do a count(case when) in Amazon Redshift.

Using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288458/in-redshift-postgres-how-to-count-rows-that-meet-a-condition), I wrote:

```
select
sfdc_account_key,
record_type_name,
vplus_stage,
vplus_stage_entered_date,
site_delivered_date,

case when vplus_stage = 'Lost' then -1 else 0 end as stage_lost_yn,
case when vplus_stage = 'Lost' then 2000 else 0 end as stage_lost_revenue,
case when vplus_stage = 'Lost' then datediff(month,vplus_stage_entered_date,CURRENT_DATE) else 0 end as stage_lost_months_since,
count(case when vplus_stage = 'Lost' then 1 else 0 end) as stage_lost_count


from shared.vplus_enrollment_dim
where record_type_name = 'APM Website';
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[42803][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "vplus_enrollment_dim.sfdc_account_key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "vplus_enrollment_dim.sfdc_account_key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;
```

Query was running fine before I added the count. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not have an aggregate function (sum, count etc) without `group by`

The syntax is like this

```
select a, count(*)
  from table
 group by a (or group by 1 in Redshift)
```

In your query you need to add

```
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

because you have 8 columns other than `count`

Since I don't know your data and use case I can not tell you it will give you the right result, but SQL will be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule is:

- If you are using an aggregate function (eg `COUNT(...)`), then you must supply a `GROUP BY` clause to define the grouping
- Exception: If all columns are aggregates (eg `SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(sales) FROM table`)
- Any columns that are *not* aggregate functions must appear in the `GROUP BY` (eg `SELECT year, month, AVG(sales) FROM table GROUP BY year, month`)

Your query has a `COUNT()` aggregate function mixed-in with non-aggregate values, which is giving rise to the error.

In looking at your query, you probably don't want to group on *all* of the columns (eg `stage_lost_revenue` and `stage_lost_months_since` don't look like likely grouping columns). You might want to mock-up a query result to figure out what you *actually* want from such a query.